# Issue opening specific images using PIL from URL repsonse

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I'm working on scraping images from URLs doing a bit of manipulation and then saving them to disk. This works on the **vast** majority of images but there are certain image URLs that fail despite loading fine in a browser. I've looked up the error trace but have had no luck with the various fixes here. The below is an example URL extracted as a failure.

> OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at...>

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

urlString = "http://lcl3.com/chemStructures1/A-10400.JPG"
response = requests.get(urlString,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},timeout=10)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) #check that it is an image; fails here
rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')
basewidth = 450
wpercent = (basewidth/float(rgb_im.size[0]))
if float(rgb_im.size[0]) > 450:                     
    hsize = int((float(rgb_im.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    rgb_im.save(image_folder / image_file_name,optimize=True,quality=95)
```

I presume the file is of a different format. For extra reference the line fails at:

response = requests.get(urlString,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},timeout=10)

and gives the above trace. I'm sure it's probably a one-liner but have torn my hair out over it so any ideas warmly appreciated!

Edit:

I'm finding more links failing. e.g.

> http://www.excelscientific.com/sealplate.jpg 
>   https://www.bioexpress.com/stibo/web/std.lang.all/52/52/4695252.jpg

I've looked at the source code and can't distinguish any difference (there doesn't appear to be any 'content' on these pages just images so I'm getting more confident it's an image format issue.

Comment: If you look at the data you get back you'll see it is caused by MOD_SECURITY denying your access because of an unacceptable type.

Comment: Thanks this is blindingly obvious I was so fixated on the image conversion this basic check didn't even register. The irony is stripping the header completely makes it work.